# Where is the best place to hunt rabbits in Lost Ark?

Tags: lost-ark

I have a guild quest to hunt rabbits, but they always seem quite rare to find.

Is there a specific map with a high concentration of rabbits so that I can quickly complete my quest?

Comment: The area where you get the hunting ability has a ton of them. I don't remember the name though.

Comment: That would be Bilbrin Forest then I guess? https://lostarkmap.com/index.html?s=bilbrin+forest

Comment: If you level up your stronghold and get access to the farm and caves, you can hunt uncontested. Life skill guild quests count in your stronghold so it's arguably the fastest way.